# Angular call function onLoad

Tags: angular, typescript

so my problem is, that how do i call a function when the component is fully loaded in angular?

I tried with:
 `<body onload='func()'></body>` and its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for [ngOnInit](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) or [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyfirstApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body  onload='func()'>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
<script>
function func(){
  alert("hello")
}
  </script>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]0qlm.png

[image]com/z